# Pipe echo of associative array into dmenu

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a arr
arr+=(
[mirror]="xrandr --output hdmi-1 --same-as edp-1"
[extend]="xrandr --output hdmi-1 --auto"
)
screen=hdmi-1

chosen=$(echo -e ${!arr[@]}| dmenu -fn monospace-14)

[ "$chosen" != "" ] || exit
```

But when I run this, `mirror` and `extend` are the same item.

Is there a way to get this into two separate items?

To print multiple items you do this:

```
echo -e "first\nsecond\nthird" | dmenu
```

I used an associative array because then I only need to write the options once, and adding options is very easy (just append the list).

Comment: Are you wanting to use `bash` or `sh`?  Your code explicitly uses `sh` but the question is tagged `bash`.  Please clarify.  n. b. I'm pretty sure `sh` does not have associative arrays.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Im using bash. Thats a typo sry

Comment: Shouldn't it be `declare -A` (upper case) for an **associative** array (as opposed to `declare -a` for an indexed array)?

Comment: +1 That is so amazingl! I never heard about declare -A before. I am feeling like a idiot for all scripts that I wrote without knowing about that. So that is the OP's problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `printf` instead of `echo` to format the inputs separated by newlines:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A arr
arr+=(
[mirror]="xrandr --output hdmi-1 --same-as edp-1"
[extend]="xrandr --output hdmi-1 --auto"
)

choice=$(printf "%s\n" "${!arr[@]}" | dmenu -fn monospace-14)

# Execute choice if dmenu returns ok:
[ $? = 0 ] && ${arr[$choice]}
```

Note that `declare -a` is for just an indexed array while `declare -A` is for an associative array. The quotes around the `printf` arguments let you use keys that include space characters.